# Best way to structure has_many through with several models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am setting up a database of textbooks.  A `Book` will look something like this:

**Book**

- id
- title
- isbn
- authors
- subjects
- classes
- universities
- professors

While a book would (obviously) only have one title or ISBN - I would like authors, subjects, universities, and professors to be a type of "tag". A book can be written by multiple authors, be used for multiple subjects in multiple classes taught by multiple professors. So I would like to setup a many-to-many relationship for each of those. e.g. an `Author` might look something like:

**Author**

- id
- name
- books

It doesn't necessarily make sense to me for book to belong to author, or vise versa (though I could be wrong.) But I also don't know that creating a `book_author_associations` table, a `book_jubjects_associations` model, a `book_classes_associations` model, etc.

What is the best way to go about creating multiple many to manys like this?

Comment: If you don't want to create join models you can use associations of the `has_and_belongs_to_many` type. They only take a join table in your database, but no additional ActiveRecord model. More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Polymorphic associations? A model like BookAssociations which refer to a book_id, associated_object_id and associated_object_type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No test, but should work in theory:

```
Book
  has_many :book_associations
  has_many :associations, through: :book_associations

BookAssociation
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :association, polymorphic: true
  validates :book_id, presence: true
  validates :association_id, presence: true
  validates :association_type, presence: true

Author
  has_many :book_associations, as: :association
  has_many :books, through: :book_associations

Subject
  has_many :book_associations, as: :association
  has_many :books, through: :book_associations
```

Answer (score 1):

Having join tables is unavoidable in this situation.

You should go ahead and create separate tables for classes, subjects, authors, etc, because they have very different attributes. You should associate them with books through join tables that for the most part will have their own attributes.

For example, a contributor to a book could be an author, or they could be an editor, or a photographer, or a translator, or any number of other roles, and that role would be an attribute of the association between books and authors (better to call them contributors).

For more information on this sort of thing you might look at EDItEUR's Onix codelists for ideas about book metadata structure. http://www.editeur.org/14/Code-Lists/